# how can I do file operations on linux?

Tags: c, linux

I want to parent and child process read the contents of a.txt file, byte by byte. And  parent process  write byte by byte to the b.txt file. child process write byte by byte to the c.txt file.

Parent and child are working on reading from the same file and writing to the same file

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<fcntl.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<sys/wait.h>
    
int main(argc,argv)
int argc;
char *argv[];
{
    int fdrt,fdwt2,fdwt3;
    char c;
    char parent='P';
    char child='C';
    int pid;
    unisigned long i;
    
    if(argc !=4) exit(1);
    if((fdrd =open(argv[1],O_RDONLY))==-1)  
        exit(1);
       
    if((fdwt2=creat(argv[2],0666))==-1)  
        exit(1);
    if((fdwt3=creat(argv[3],0666))==-1)  
        exit(1);
     printf("Parent:creating a child process\n");
    pid=fork();
    if(pid==0){
    printf("Child process starts,id= %d\n",getpid());
    for(;;)
    {
        if(read(fdrd,&c,1)!=1) break;
        if(i=0;i<50000;i++);
    
        write(1,&child,1);
        write(fdwt2,&c,1);     
    }
    exit(0);
}
else
{
    printf("Parent starts,id= %d\n",getpid());
    for(;;)
    {
        if(read(fdrd,&c,1)!=1) break;
        if(i=0;i<50000;i++);
    
        write(1,&parent,1);
        write(fdwt3,&c,1);     
    }
    wait(0);
}
}
```

Comment: Aside: the modern definition style is `int main(int argc, char *argv[])`. You are using the old K&R (Kernighan and Ritchie) style.

Comment: Just what is `if(i=0;i<50000;i++);` supposed to do?

Comment: You have syntax problems in your code. You have `else` without `if` and mismatched braces.

Comment: You write that the parent is writing to `b.txt` and the child is writing to `c.txt`, and that they are writing to the same file.  Are `b.txt` and `c.txt` names for the same file?  If not, where is the typo?

Comment: What is the actual question, specifically?  The title is much too broad.

Comment: It looks like the code that calls `fork()` is missing.

Comment: The code does not contain `fork`, so it will not start a child process. Please make sure you copy&paste exactly the code you compile and run on your system.

Comment: I am really curious about what the semantics of `int main() {} else {}` ought to be.

Comment: Your final `else {` block is _outside_ of the body of `main`. You want `main` to have an `pid_t pid = fork(); if (pid == 0) { child_stuff } else { parent_stuff; wait(NULL); }` inside.

Comment: Also, using _files_ to dynamically communicate between parent and child would be better served with _two_ `pipe` calls rather than `open/creat`

Comment: i created an a.txt  and wrote an text in it. I want the parent process to write the text it reads from this a.txt to b.txt , and I want the child process to write to c.txt, but it doesn't work. but when I edit the code, let the parent and child read it from a.txt and write it to the b.txt, it works in. @John Bollinger

Answer (score 0):

Even if you found a way of reading and writing to the same file at the same time, it is probably unwise and may lead to data corruption. If you really need two processes and really need to read and write to a.txt from both you can do it by opening reading/writing and closing the file each time you read/write data. This would be safe but the performance wouldn't be good.

If you're only reading from parent and child you can just open after the fork without issue so it is opened for read twice.

You can write to b.txt from the parent only and write to c.txt from the child only without issue by opening those files after the fork().

To communicate between parent and child process efficiently, you can use pipes, but the amount of data you can send in a pipe is not as large as in a file. Using a file for this purpose when a pipe would do the trick is probably bad practice.

Comment: Why would you need to open and close the files? He's not using stdio, so there's no buffering that needs to be worked around.

Comment: This my homework, to learn race condition. @Barmar

Comment: Opening and closing the file won't solve the race condition. You need to use a mutex.

Comment: The locks on the file will prevent data corruption from attempting to read or write from a file opened for read/write in another process. Mutexes are for multi threaded applications which is not the case here. If you know how to use them in this case, please expand.

Answer (score 0):

When you `open` or `creat` a file, the system creates a kernel "file object" that tracks the open file (tracking where in the file you are reading/writing, among other things) and returns a "file descriptor" that refers to it.  That file descriptor is just a handle, and you can have mulitple file descriptors that refer to the same file object.

When you `fork` a child, the child gets a copy of all the parents file descriptors, but the file objects are *not* copied -- the file descriptors in the child refer to the same file object.  So when you `open` the read file and then `fork`, the parent and child *share* a file object for that file, which means that when either one reads from the file, it advances the read location in the file, so when the other one reads from the file, it will get bytes from that advanced point rather than the start.

The net effect is that the bytes in the source file will be "split" between your parent and child -- each process will get some but not all of the bytes.  Which bytes go to which depends on timing and is hard to predict.

To avoid this, you want to `open` the source file *after* calling fork.  This will result in opening the file twice (once in the parent and once in the child), thus creating two file objects to track the read location, and allowing parent and child to read the file independently.